# Python: Opening multiple images in Windows Image Viewer and multiple of such windows in each corner

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, image, window

I am a beginner and I am sure this is simple, but I could not for the life of me find the solution by googling.

In a folder, I have 9 photos. I currently, highlight a couple of them and right click and open in default image viewer and then place the window in the corner, and then do that for the rest of the images in this arrangement:

[All Photos in Folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZN1Q.png)

[All Photos Opened in each corner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mSxA.png)

This way I can mouse over for example the left top corner window and scroll with my mouse and it would scroll between image 1.png and 2.png. If I hover over the right top corner and scroll with my mouse wheel the images would scroll between 3.png, 4.png, and 5.png. Same for the other two windows. At the moment I have a lot of images that  I have to open manually and configure like this. I wanted to write a simple script that would automatically open up these images in this way and arrange them in each corner.

I found some ways of opening a single image, but could not find a way to open multiple images in a single instance of a photo viewer nor how to reposition such window.

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open('example.jpg')
img.show()
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably not the best way to do the task in my original question, but after enabling the original Windows Photo Viewer in Windows 10 following this guide: [How-to-make-windows-photo-viewer-your-default-image-viewer-on-windows-10](https://www.howtogeek.com/225844/how-to-make-windows-photo-viewer-your-default-image-viewer-on-windows-10/)

I have made 4 folders with the appropriate pictures in each one (for the top left, top right, bottom left, and bottom right corners).

I have then made the default app to open the png images with Windows Photo Viewer.

Installed win32gui:

```
pip install win32gui
```

Then I wrote this script which seems to work:

```
import os
import win32gui
import time

FIRST_PATH = 'C:\\Gale\\Img_test\\left_bottom\\6.png'
SECOND_PATH = 'C:\\Gale\\Img_test\\left_top\\1.png'
THIRD_PATH = 'C:\\Gale\\Img_test\\right_bottom\\8.png'
FOURTH_PATH = 'C:\\Gale\\Img_test\\right_top\\3.png'

folder_paths = [FIRST_PATH, SECOND_PATH, THIRD_PATH, FOURTH_PATH]

TOP_RIGHT_COORD = [954,0,980,530]
TOP_LEFT_COORD = [-10,0,980,530]
BOTTOM_RIGHT_COORD = [954,515,980,530]
BOTTOM_LEFT_COORD = [-10,515,980,530]


def openCharts(paths):
    for path in paths:
        os.startfile(path)

def enumHandler(hwnd, lParam):
     if win32gui.IsWindowVisible(hwnd):
         if '1.png' in win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd):
             win32gui.MoveWindow(hwnd, TOP_LEFT_COORD[0], TOP_LEFT_COORD[1], TOP_LEFT_COORD[2],TOP_LEFT_COORD[3], True)
         elif '3.png' in win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd):
             win32gui.MoveWindow(hwnd, TOP_RIGHT_COORD[0], TOP_RIGHT_COORD[1], TOP_RIGHT_COORD[2],TOP_RIGHT_COORD[3], True)
         elif '6.png' in win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd):
             win32gui.MoveWindow(hwnd, BOTTOM_LEFT_COORD[0], BOTTOM_LEFT_COORD[1], BOTTOM_LEFT_COORD[2],BOTTOM_LEFT_COORD[3], True)
         elif '8.png' in win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd):
             win32gui.MoveWindow(hwnd, BOTTOM_RIGHT_COORD[0], BOTTOM_RIGHT_COORD[1], BOTTOM_RIGHT_COORD[2],BOTTOM_RIGHT_COORD[3],  True)

openCharts(folder_paths)
time.sleep(0.5)
win32gui.EnumWindows(enumHandler, None)
```